# Stata: Fail at setting global pathname

Tags: stata

I have a `profile.do`, where it states

```
global prog "C:\Users\foobar\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Projects\Labor Supply\LIAB_QM2_9310_v1_test_dta\prog"
```

Then I have a different stata `different.do` file, where this variable is supposed to be set

```
adopath ++ $prog
```

However, this turns to not work out. So I tried to discover the root of the error:

```
. display $prog
C:\Users\foobar\Google invalid name
```

Using `'` instead of `"` didn't help:

```
. global prog 'C:\Users\sdaro\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Projects\Labor Supply\LIAB_QM2_9310_v1_test_dta\prog'

. display $prog
'C:\Users\sdaro\Google invalid name
r(198);
```

It seems like it's trying to replace `Drive` with something, but I don't get what. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your path has blanks, so you need surrounding quotes. The quotes used when *defining* the macro are meant to be delimiters. When invoked, `display` and `adopath` will strip them out.

```
global prog "C:\Users\foobar\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Projects\Labor Supply\LIAB_QM2_9310_v1_test_dta\prog"

display "$prog"

adopath ++ "$prog"
```

If you're not allowed to change `adopath $prog`, you can protect the original quotes with double quotes:

```
global prog ""C:\Users\foobar\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Projects\Labor Supply\LIAB_QM2_9310_v1_test_dta\prog""

display $prog

adopath ++ $prog
```

Notice the original error you received:

```
. display $prog
C:\Users\foobar\Google invalid name
```

Because you didn't use quotes, Stata assumed a variable name, and what you have there is an illegal name (can't have `:` or `\` or blanks).

Comment: FooBar, I think you misunderstood. Roberto's second example, containing the double quotes, creates a global variable that when used in the adopath statements succeeds in adding the new directory, spaces and all, to the front of the adopath.

Comment: One last follow-up: Part of the later code (that I cannot touch) was also `do "$prog/additionalPath"`. However, this specification leads to an error: `display "$prog/additionalPath"` gives me again a `invalid name` error. Is there an alternative to double quotes that still allows me to do this operation in this manner?

Comment: I take it you've changed the original path in the `global prog` and added your own path. Is this correct? If so, did the original path have a blank? If the new path you are using had no blanks, you wouldn't have any problem. If you insist on using a path with blanks, but you're not able to make changes to other parts of code then you need to wait for someone to post some other solution. If you can add code (but not delete original code), you can redefine the `global` whenever you need to. It works, but it doesn't look or feel right.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Almost: I cannot see the original `profile.do`, so I have no idea whether or not the original path contained blanks. I think that, with all these information, I will write up a new question that is more precise on where the problem lies.