# Stata: store pathname with forbidden characters in variable

Tags: stata

I am working with *institution A*'s code, which contains among other things,

```
adopath ++ $prog
use "$prog/subDirectory/otherFile.do"
```

The actual do file is something I try not to change, as I know in its current state, it will work with *institution A*.

I am to define my own `profile.do` in order to make it works, where I need to set up `$prog`. I cannot see how *institution A* set up their `profile.do`, and whether it contains forbidden characters. `$prog` is supposed to contain the working directory, which in my case is

```
global prog "C:\Users\foobar\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Projects\Labor Supply\LIAB_QM2_9310_v1_test_dta\prog"
```

As I learned [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626827/stata-fail-at-setting-global-pathname), spaces are forbidden characters, which is why this setup definitively will not work. I was suggested to use double quotes,

```
global prog ""C:\Users\foobar\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Projects\Labor Supply\LIAB_QM2_9310_v1_test_dta\prog""
```

These worked fine to some extent, `adopath ++ $prog` was running smoothly now. However, the second command, `use "$prog/subDirectory/otherFile.do"`, contains an error now. So here is my question

- First best: is there a different way of defining `$prog` in a way that allows me to run the remainder of the code without getting errors?
- Second best: Is there a safe way to rewrite `use "$prog/subDirectory/otherFile.do"`? That is, if I rewrite it as `use $prog"/subDirectory/otherFile.do"`, and it proceeds working on my system, am I guaranteed it to work wherever the old code used to work? Can I safely exchange that piece of code while guaranteeing continued functionality?

Answer (score 2):

The second best:

*profile.do*

```
global prog "C:\Users\foobar\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Projects\Labor Supply\LIAB_QM2_9310_v1_test_dta\prog"
```

*Institution A's code*

```
capture adopath ++ $prog
if (_rc != 0) adopath ++ "$prog"

use "$prog/subDirectory/otherFile.do"
```

Being really picky, you would substitute the `!=` for `==`, and `0` for the expected error code; for example `198` (for `invalid syntax`).

This solution respects the original code and, if necessary, will adequately handle the error produced by your **profile.do** file.

(Again, this wouldn't be a problem if your working directory had no blanks.)